# unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.pages.product-type.application' for platform 'iphoneos'

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I want to create flutter app for
iphone and Android.

In Android project working fine.
but i check project in xcode get this error please help.

unable to resolve product type 'com.apple.pages.product-type.application' for platform 'iphoneos'

Comment: Make sure that your target platforms in xCode are iOS phones and not watches for example. can you confirm?

Comment: Yes I chek xCode target platform are iOS phones.